# Reopening a closed, migrated question doesn't cancel migration rejection

Tags: bug, status-declined, migration, migration-rejection, reopened-questions

This question:

- https://superuser.com/questions/503400/all-servers-under-salt-water-is-it-possible-to-recover-data-from-each-platter-o/503402#503402

Was migrated over to Server Fault

- [All servers flooded by salt water, is it possible to recover data from multi-platter drives?](https://serverfault.com/questions/447092/all-servers-flooded-by-salt-water-is-it-possible-to-recover-data-from-multi-pla)

Looking at the [history of the Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/447092/all-servers-flooded-by-salt-water-is-it-possible-to-recover-data-from-multi-pla) version of the question, the question was closed and then reopened. However, the Super User version of the question shows as "Closed as off Topic" instead of migrated, since it was closed first.

Shouldn't the reopened stature reflect back on the migrated question?

Comment: In the general case, probably not. Since the question becomes unlocked on the original site after the initial rejection, managing the state based on the reopening on another site seems complicated. The real issue here seems to be that the post was closed for the purpose of clearing existing close votes, which doesn't mesh well with the migration rejection functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This is an edge case I'm not terribly interested in fixing.

The case where a post is migrated, then closed, then reopened is already pretty crazy.  Since the end result is still a closed (correctly) and open (correctly) post, I don't think it's worth the extra complexity just to restore the link to the migrated question.

Answer (score 1):

It would be quite helpful to automatically recover "migrated to" notice and re-direction at source site if the question was closed-then-reopened at target site.

Closing and reopening questions in my experience are not that much of an [edge case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155699/165773), but rather part of routine "quality control" at the sites with active community.

It would be quite helpful if improving question quality via closing then reopening (which is sometimes the [most efficient approach](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161877/165773)) at target site would be treated like a regular, successful migration.

---

Example (good) question that has been recently migrated from SO to Programmers, then closed and reopened there is:

- [Is Ken Thompson's compiler hack still a threat?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184874/is-ken-thompsons-compiler-hack-still-a-threat-yes-no-why)

At Programmers, the question has a notice that refers reader back to "source site":

> **migrated from [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529255/is-ken-thompsons-compiler-hack-still-a-threat-yes-no-why?noredirect=1)...**

"Source site" version of above question though does not have respective "migrated to" notice, nor re-direction, making reader incorrectly assume that question has been just closed:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529255/is-ken-thompsons-compiler-hack-still-a-threat-yes-no-why