# Why is this question about ruby frameworks considered not constructive?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions, not-constructive

I stumbled across this question about ruby frameworks, and found a **[great, informative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875941/possible-to-make-ruby-web-apps-without-a-framework/15880065#15880065)**.

> Is it possible to make a web app in ruby without using a framework? And if yes, why are frameworks chosen by most ruby web developers?

Although the question itself is broad and possibly borderline for Stack Overflow, it seems (at least to me) that the accepted answer is good enough to redeem a poor question and "make the Internet a better place".

At this point, is the question really Not Constructive?

Comment: Nothing can improve that question save for deletion. The answer might be a good one in the right setting but in this one becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment I disagree that the setting makes the answer irrelevant. I just read though it and it is a very good answer. I have been working with ruby on rails for 2 years now and I learned something about ruby from that answer. Yes the question is broad. But consider the context. The guy who asked it probably isn't looking for a book he is looking for a place to start. And that answer does a very good job of addressing the question *within that context*.

Comment: Unfortunately, now that you brought it up the _deleters_ have jumped on it and killed.  We lose good content every day because of some people who think that even a great answer that doesn't fit their little paradigm should be killed, instead of letting it help the people who appreciate it.  It's been discussed in the past, and old questions with good answers are supposed to be left alone, but a lot of people don't care about those rules.

Comment: @LanceRoberts That's no old question, it's a couple days. The 'good' answer was some sort of blog post spiel, and this is the paradigm we've been conditioned to enact.

Comment: I'm starting to think we're going over the top with these closings. The question clearly *has* a specific background in Ruby (as far as I understand the Ruby scene). It's not a random "can xyz be done in abc" type question.

Comment: Voted to undelete.

Comment: question is deleted now, making it impossible to discuss for anyone with less than 10K at SO. It would be better to undelete it (and lock as "content dispute") at least while meta discussion on it is active

Comment: I am of the opinion that questions with good answers should never be deleted, regardless of the quality of the question. If a question doesn't fit for SO, close it, yes, but don't delete the question if it's accumulated a good answer.

Comment: @Pekka웃 It is now undeleted.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Thoughts have been thrown :P

Comment: Nobody really wants to save it because nobody has edited it in a way that's not asking for a long blog post to qualify it.

Comment: flagged to lock while content dispute is going on

Comment: @gnat Keep in mind that locking would prevent any edits to better ground the question, and perhaps edits to improve either answer even more. I looked at how the question could be better anchored in the first answer, and perhaps adding some references, but I don't know enough about Ruby to be effective. I'm hoping that if something is going to stave off deletion, it'll be an improvement to the question itself. That's what needs to happen ultimately if it's going to stay around. Still, I'm leaving it up to the mods.

Comment: I see that the big problem here is the second part of the question: "And if yes, why are frameworks chosen by most ruby web developers?". Maybe we could delete it entirely from both question and answers?

Comment: @Jueecy The issue is that without that part of the question then the only real answer is "Yes".  None of the rest of either answer because on topic any more.  That's not a particularly useful question/answer anymore.

Comment: @Jueecy - That's a great suggestion. It would make the question much more specific, eliminates the elements that could solicit debate/arguments/etc, and does not require many (any?) changes to the answer...

Comment: The only question there actually is "How do I build a web app using Ruby without a framework?"

Comment: @Servy - No, the answer says "Yes" and then proceeds to explain in great detail how you would start. And why you might not want to do this (IE, developing apps for production).

Comment: @TimPost I understand what locking mean pretty well. Would want just that in order to allow us discuss "Why is this question about ruby frameworks considered not constructive?" without hurry (and without being unable to read the answer if it gets deleted - see **"Voted to redelete"** above). After all, if the question is good-in-heart and salvageable through editing, this could be done after lock expiry doesn't it?

Comment: @Servy, I disagree: nobody cares about my point of view on frameworks and I wrote the second part of that answer just because it needed to match the question (and maybe I was wrong there). The answer to the second question can be pretty much summed to: frameworks make development fast. Nobody really need this answer because it is the slogan of most frameworks already. Yet I agree with you on the point that the only real answer there would then become "Yes". Then maybe we can explicitly add the "And if it is possible, how?" part to the question as well.

Comment: @Jueecy if you add that in then yes, the answer becomes mostly on topic again.  The problem with adding it is that it changes the question from not constructive to not a real question as it has now become overly broad.  You could write a book on how to write applications in Ruby without a framework (which is an example in the FAQ of the definition of too broad of a question).

Comment: NARQ by criteria of "incomplete". 1) "Is it possible to make a web app in ruby without using a framework?" -> OP needs to clarify what have they tried before asking this. 2) "why are frameworks chosen by most ruby web developers?" -> OP needs to explain why they think so, where did they got that idea

Comment: @gnat Well, at the time of this writing, it needs only one reopen vote and delete votes have not gained any velocity .. so I'm pretty confident that not intervening at this time is probably the best call. I don't completely disagree with you - as you said locking it could make sense, but .. I think it's more than the least amount of intervention needed _at this point_.

Comment: The question has been reopened.

Comment: @TimPost hmm reopening a [clear NARQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176134/why-is-this-question-about-ruby-frameworks-considered-not-constructive?noredirect=1#comment528700_176134 "as explained here") (and thus opening it to [gather garbage answers that may block further edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161877/165773)), with the sole purpose to prevent MSO-inducted deletions. Sounds pretty weird

Comment: @gnat There's nothing "incomplete" about part 1, what they've tried is irrelevant. They're not asking *how*, they're asking *if*. Part 2 isn't incomplete either, I think it's pretty well established that most developers use existing tools. A tiny minority may not.

Comment: @Servy, good point. Then I definitely think that it should be closed. But it seems that the answers have been useful to at least someone to start from there and build their own answer. Therefore I'm obviously against deletion as greatly explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176134/why-is-this-question-about-ruby-frameworks-considered-not-constructive#comment528621_176134).

Comment: @Jueecy I agree it shouldn't be deleted here, just closed.  I'm not sure why so many people are voting to reopen it.  It's pretty obvious that at least in it's current state it's both not constructive and NARQ.  Even you've said that it should be closed, yet you voted to reopen it.

Comment: @DaveNewton well to me if-part of the question is as incomplete as it gets. I believe that _"it just popped in my head, if...?"_ is substantially different from _"studying `<list of tutorials>` and searching web for `<list of search terms>` left me wondering, if...?"_

Comment: @gnat IMO Which is why I think it's NARQ because of lack of research/obviousness. If the question was "complete" by your definition it wouldn't have needed to be asked. IMO a "complete" question would be even *more* NARQy, but for my reason, not yours.

Comment: @DaveNewton you mean, "complete" question wouldn't have if-part at all?

Comment: @gnat No, I mean that by "complete", would answer itself, and not have been a question.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't follow sorry - "would... not have been a question", how is that different from what I wrote "wouldn't have if-part at all"?

Comment: @gnat ... I neither understand what you're asking nor am particularly interested in this sub-thread. None of the question is necessary with any amount of research > 0. The answer to the first part is "yes", discoverable by research, the answer to the second part is "because [barrage of answers that are language-neutral]", discoverable by research. If the question was complete, both parts would have been answered before it was posted. IMO there's no way to ask this as a "complete" question, by your definition, without it answering itself. Carry on.

Comment: @DaveNewton oh I see. As far as I can tell, our views essentially converge. I mean, unlike you, I don't know answers to if- and why- parts - but(!) I know requirements to make these parts "complete". Now, if fulfilling _my_ requirements leads to _your_ outcome (question not being asked at all), I would be 100% fine with that. Fair enough?

Comment: @TimPost note that all this funny reopen/redelete ping-pong eventually ended by question being _locked_ - [just as I wrote it should be](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176134/why-is-this-question-about-ruby-frameworks-considered-not-constructive#comment528696_176134 "few comments above here"). "Content dispute" lock is there for a reason...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When evaluating a post for deletion, consider the following question: *"On the whole, is the Internet better or worse because this post is here?"*

Closing is not the same thing at all.  By leaving the post on the site in its closed state, people on the Internet can still benefit from the information contained in the well-written answer, without the question itself being fodder for arguments and opinions.

My vote:  Closed: Yes.  Deleted: No.

Comment: It's worth noting that a lot of people are not only voting to undelete (which I support) but voting to reopen (there are currently 3 reopen votes, so a total of 8 people have voted to reopen).  When the bikeshedders have the 3k rep to vote to reopen ensuring that the question stays in a closed but not deleted state can only be done with locking.

Comment: @Servy: If it reopens, I'm going to close it again.

Comment: @Robert - please do (close it again).  Just note that many of us are voting to re-open as a way to prevent it from being deleted.  (Re-opening it *does* clear away all delete votes, right?)

Comment: I have an idea about writing a web app in another language. Is it a good idea to add a new question about that?

Comment: Robert - do you have a link to that old SO question on "Favorite foods to eat while coding"?  That might be a good example of a delete-worthy question satisfying your criterion.

Comment: @Jueecy.new: No.

Comment: @Jueecy.new: Hell to freeze over.

Comment: @Jueecy.new: So was my answer.  This is one of those rare cases where the deletionists are just going to try and delete the question, and the inclusionists are just going to try and reopen it.  Neither state is ideal.

Comment: @Jueecy.new: Unless some other mod decides to override my decision, yes.  Or, we can get some kind of consensus here.

Comment: @Jueecy.new: Look at the [question's history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15875941/revisions).

Comment: @Jueecy.new: Well, it currently has 3 reopen votes and 2 delete votes, so I disagree that consensus has been achieved.  Why do you want it unlocked?

Comment: @Jueecy.new: Wat?  If the question gets deleted, any rep you gained on the post will go right down the toilet.

Comment: @Jueecy.new How long are we going to keep talking about this question? >_<

Comment: I've cleared the discussion above because it was dumb as hell by my part and I was ashamed of it. :D

Answer (score 9):

This question qualifies for being "too broad." The short answer is "yes." The long answer is "in an infinite number of ways."

While many questions may have useful answers, we're looking for question which seek out specific knowledge. As it stands, someone could dump ten years' experience into an answer, and still not completely answer this question.

It is thus not constructive for StackOverflow, where we look for specific answers and details. This is likely to start into a debate over the *best way* to build said website, or provide conflicting information from conflicting experience.

Regardless of the quality of the question, I am of the opinion that questions with good answers should never be deleted. If a question doesn't fit for SO, close it, yes, but don't delete the question if it's accumulated a good answer.

In short, questions should have definitive answers. While this one may have had a helpful answer, there is no way to provide an absolute solution.

Comment: "As it stands, someone could dump ten years' experience into an answer, and still not completely answer this question." It's true, but it would be a very informative answer nonetheless.

Comment: @Jueecy Hence, while the question should be closed, I don't think it should be deleted.

Comment: And a brand new delete vote.  I guess some people think deleting that answer along with the question will "Make the internet better"

Answer (score 7):

The question as written is too open-ended and broad to be answered without debate.

> Is it possible to make a web app in ruby without using a framework? And if yes, why are frameworks chosen by most ruby web developers?

This clearly fall into the definition of not-constructive:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but ***this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.*** If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, [see the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) for guidance.

I added the emphasis to point out the key reason this question is not constructive.  It could lead to extended discussion on *why frameworks* are chosen by ruby developers.  Answers should be definitive and should not lead to debates.

The answer, that you point out as great, demonstrates the problem with the question by pointing out **pros** and **cons** to frameworks - are these opinions or facts that are being outlined.  If they are factual, then there should be references to support these claims.

Comment: Your point about references for the pros and cons is a very good one.

Answer (score 4):

The question fails on multiple points, but for me, obviousness/lack of research is tops.

1. Obviously we don't *have* to use a framework, because the language can *support* a framework–therefore the mechanisms for writing a web app exist in the ecosystem.
2. *Why* to use a framework is language-neutral, and documented all over the place.

I find the answer too long, with only the TL;DR and Pros/Cons sections interesting.

Other resources for *how* to write a web app in Ruby, using a variety of mechanisms, exist, and the topic is too broad for a good SO answer. There was no call for an *example* of one.